# Questions about App IDs

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, ad-hoc-distribution

How do I delete old App IDs?

How do you make the iOS Team Provisioning Profile select a specific App ID?

Additional: Can anyone explain you need to code sign 4 times with the selected profile when Distributing for Ad-Hoc Deployment?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, there is currently no way to delete App ID's.

I use Simon Whitaker's plug-in for Chrome, which allows you to have a little more control over your App IDs and how they appear.

It might be worth checking out:
https://github.com/simonwhitaker/app-id-sanity/

-EDIT-

Just realised it works with Safari too.

-EDIT2-

Regarding your follow up, in the provisioning portal, after choosing to create a new App ID, you can select the App ID you want from a list:

[image]

Once you've completed it and downloaded it, drop it into the Xcode organiser and then select it from the `Code signing` section of the `Build Settings` of your Xcode project:

[image]

Comment: Oh, thank you! What an interesting tool, we're in the same situation as the creator of that tool: we have created too many. 

But do you know how to make the Xcode managed provisioning profile (iOS Team Provisioning Profile) select a specific App ID? The App IDs are not listed in alphabetical or chronological order and it selects one starting with the letter "N". It used to select "Xcode: iOS Wildcard AppID", but then it changed.

Also, do you have any idea Xcode wants to sign 4 times upon exporting an APP as an IPA? We've Googled for this, but we can't seem to find out why it does this.

Comment: Not entirely sure I follow. If it's what I think you mean, you need the bundle ID of your project in Xcode to match the bundle ID of the provisioning profile.

Comment: Yeah, I am maybe unclear about what I mean. But when Xcode connects to the provisioning portal itself, it will create a provisioning profile (that says it's "Managed by Xcode"), and Xcode will select an App ID for this profile. It once created and also used to select "Xcode: iOS Wildcard AppID". But now it uses a different one, an App ID we don't want it to use. We would like to be able to specify a different App ID for this profile, but we can't seem to find a way and we have no idea why it chooses what it does. Thank you very much for taking your time to help us out!

Comment: I've edited my answer which will hopefully be a little clearer.